# PDO is not liking my query

Tags: mysql, pdo

So i'm having the follow prepared query:

```
INSERT INTO messages (email,receiver,name,message,created_at,batch_id) VALUES (:email, :receiver, :name, :message, :created_at, (SELECT main_table.batch_id FROM batch_id AS main_table))
```

When i execute this, a new record is created but batch_id is always 0 when it should be 1.

So i debugged the stmt and it returns the following sent query:

```
INSERT INTO messages (email,receiver,name,message,created_at,batch_id) VALUES ('jmy@email.com', 'My name', 'Not my name', 'My message to not my name', '2017-11-21 12:33:07', (SELECT main_table.batch_id FROM batch_id AS main_table))
```

The query looks good and when i manually execute it in Sequel Pro, the batch_id is 1 as it should be.

Why is it that PDO isn't doing what it's supposed to do?

Comment: the described behavior is highly improbable. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve) so anyone will be able to confirm it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Somewhere down the line an update query snuck in, which was messing up the data.